# Not Exists not playing well with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, exists

This has to be something simple that I have just missed...

I've got a temp table say this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tsa
(
    AttendeeID int,
    SurveyID int,
    TrainingAttendeeID int
)
```

I get a single record using TOP 1 with something similar to this:

```
SELECT
        TOP 1
        @AttendeeID=ta.AttendeeID,
        @SurveyID=ts.SurveyID,
        @TrainingAttendeeID = ta.TrainingAttendeeID
    FROM            
        TrainingAttendee ta
    INNER JOIN
        [User] u
    ON
        u.UserID= ta.AttendeeID
    INNER JOIN
        [Training] t
    ON
        t.TrainingID = ta.TrainingID
    INNER JOIN
        [TrainingSet] ts
    ON
        ts.TrainingSetID = t.TrainingSetID
    WHERE
        ta.AttendedTraining = 1
        AND ta.ConfirmAttendedEmailOn IS NOT NULL
        --only get people who didn't fill out the survey
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SurveyTaken st WHERE st.AddedByUserID = ta.AttendeeID AND st.SurveyID = ts.SurveyID)
    ORDER BY
        ta.AttendeeID,
        ts.SurveyID
```

As soon as I get this one record I store it into my temp table as such:

```
--insert into our temp table
INSERT INTO #tsa(AttendeeID, SurveyID, TrainingAttendeeID) 
VALUES(@AttendeeID, @SurveyID, @TrainingAttendeeID)
```

Then I need to go through this whole procedure of checking some data and sending an email...as soon as that email is sent I need to pick up the next record not including the record I had previously...So without showing too much code:

```
WHILE SomeCondition
BEGIN
  --do some thing...

  --pick up next one
--grab next one
                SELECT
                    TOP 1
                    @AttendeeID = ta.AttendeeID,
                    @SurveyID=ts.SurveyID,
                    @TrainingAttendeeID=ta.TrainingAttendeeID
                FROM            
                    TrainingAttendee ta
                INNER JOIN
                    [User] u
                ON
                    u.UserID= ta.AttendeeID
                INNER JOIN
                    [Training] t
                ON
                    t.TrainingID = ta.TrainingID
                INNER JOIN
                    [TrainingSet] ts
                ON
                    ts.TrainingSetID = t.TrainingSetID
                WHERE
                    (
                        --same where as original
                        ta.AttendedTraining = 1
                        AND (ta.ConfirmAttendedEmailOn IS NOT NULL)
                        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SurveyTaken st WHERE st.AddedByUserID = ta.AttendeeID AND st.SurveyID = ts.SurveyID))
                        --adding the piece such that we compare against the temp table...
                        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tsa tempS WHERE tempS.AttendeeID = ta.AttendeeID AND tempS.SurveyID = ts.SurveyID AND tempS.TrainingAttendeeID = ta.TrainingAttendeeID))
                    )
                ORDER BY
                    ta.AttendeeID,
                    ts.SurveyID

                --insert into our temp table    
                INSERT INTO #tsa(AttendeeID, SurveyID, TrainingAttendeeID) 
                VALUES(@AttendeeID, @SurveyID, @TrainingAttendeeID)
END
```

Notice the where condition inside of this..I've added one more AND...namely:

```
--adding the piece such that we compare against the temp table...
AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tSa tempS WHERE tempS.AttendeeID = ta.AttendeeID AND tempS.SurveyID = ts.SurveyID AND tempS.TrainingAttendeeID = ta.TrainingAttendeeID))
```

Just to ensure I am not reusing the record I already processed in my temp table...and you'll notice I reinsert into my temp table at the end as well...

```
--insert into our temp table    
INSERT INTO #tsa(AttendeeID, SurveyID, TrainingAttendeeID) 
VALUES(@AttendeeID, @SurveyID, @TrainingAttendeeID)
```

Every time I run this stored procedure it goes on infinitly and so I believe something is wrong with my condition at this point.  I'm having a brain fart..or maybe there is just too much noise in the office.  What am I missing here?  I placed a print statement and it keeps processing the same record...so something tells me this last condition in my where clause is incorrect.

### Edit

Here's the entire procedure...My issue is the record set only has one record in it...But the sproc continues to process this same record

```
PROCEDURE ScriptSendTrainingSurveyReminders 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @AttendeeID int
    DECLARE @TrainingAttendeeID int
    DECLARE @SurveyID int
    DECLARE @Message nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @Subject nvarchar(255)

        CREATE TABLE #tSa
        (
            AttendeeID int,
            SurveyID int,
            TrainingAttendeeID int
        )

    SELECT
        TOP 1
        @AttendeeID=ta.AttendeeID,
        @SurveyID=ts.SurveyID,
        @TrainingAttendeeID = ta.TrainingAttendeeID
    FROM            
        TrainingAttendee ta
    INNER JOIN
        [User] u
    ON
        u.UserID= ta.AttendeeID
    INNER JOIN
        [Training] t
    ON
        t.TrainingID = ta.TrainingID
    INNER JOIN
        [TrainingSet] ts
    ON
        ts.TrainingSetID = t.TrainingSetID
    WHERE
        ta.AttendedTraining = 1
        AND ta.ConfirmAttendedEmailOn IS NOT NULL
        --only get people who didn't fill out the survey
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SurveyTaken st WHERE st.AddedByUserID = ta.AttendeeID AND st.SurveyID = ts.SurveyID)
    ORDER BY
        ta.TrainingAttendeeID,
        ta.AttendeeID,
        ts.SurveyID

    --insert into our temp table
    INSERT INTO #tSa(AttendeeID, SurveyID, TrainingAttendeeID) 
    VALUES(@AttendeeID, @SurveyID, @TrainingAttendeeID)

    WHILE @TrainingAttendeeID IS NOT NULL AND @AttendeeID IS NOT NULL AND @SurveyID IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @TrainingID int
            DECLARE @Title nvarchar(50)
            DECLARE @StartDateTime nvarchar(50)
            DECLARE @EndDateTime nvarchar(50)
            DECLARE @FullName nvarchar(255)
            DECLARE @EmailAddress nvarchar(255)
            DECLARE @Description nvarchar(MAX)

            --get the one record we are on...
            SELECT 
                @TrainingID = t.TrainingID,
                @Title = t.Title,
                @StartDateTime = CAST(CONVERT(DATE, t.StartDate) AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(t.StartTimeHours AS VARCHAR(50)) + ':' + CAST(CASE WHEN LEN(t.StartTimeMinutes)=1 THEN  CAST(t.StartTimeMinutes AS VARCHAR(50)) + '0' ELSE CAST(t.StartTimeMinutes AS VARCHAR(50)) END AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(t.StartTimeAMorPM AS VARCHAR(50)),
                @EndDateTime = CAST(CONVERT(DATE, t.EndDate) AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(t.EndTimeHours AS VARCHAR(50)) + ':' + CAST(CASE WHEN LEN(t.EndTimeMinutes)=1 THEN  CAST(t.EndTimeMinutes AS VARCHAR(50)) + '0' ELSE CAST(t.EndTimeMinutes AS VARCHAR(50)) END AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(t.EndTimeAMorPM AS VARCHAR(50)),
                @Description = t.DescriptionHTML,
                @FullName = u.FullName,
                @EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress
            FROM 
                Training t 
            INNER JOIN
                TrainingAttendee ta
            ON
                t.TrainingID = ta.TrainingID
            INNER JOIN
                [User] u
            ON
                u.UserID = ta.AttendeeID
            WHERE
                ta.TrainingAttendeeID = @TrainingAttendeeID

            IF @EmailAddress IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN 
                      --Email goes out here....
                END

            --grab next one
                SELECT
                    TOP 1
                    @AttendeeID = ta.AttendeeID,
                    @SurveyID=ts.SurveyID,
                    @TrainingAttendeeID=ta.TrainingAttendeeID
                FROM            
                    TrainingAttendee ta
                INNER JOIN
                    [User] u
                ON
                    u.UserID= ta.AttendeeID
                INNER JOIN
                    [Training] t
                ON
                    t.TrainingID = ta.TrainingID
                INNER JOIN
                    [TrainingSet] ts
                ON
                    ts.TrainingSetID = t.TrainingSetID
                WHERE
                    (
                        --same where as original
                        (ta.AttendedTraining = 1)
                        AND (ta.ConfirmAttendedEmailOn IS NOT NULL)
                        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SurveyTaken st WHERE st.AddedByUserID = ta.AttendeeID AND st.SurveyID = ts.SurveyID))
                        --adding the piece such that we compare against the temp table...
                        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tSa tempS WHERE tempS.AttendeeID = ta.AttendeeID AND tempS.SurveyID = ts.SurveyID AND tempS.TrainingAttendeeID = ta.TrainingAttendeeID))
                    )
                ORDER BY
                    ta.TrainingAttendeeID,
                    ta.AttendeeID,
                    ts.SurveyID

                PRINT CAST('TrainingAttendeeID: ' + CAST(@TrainingAttendeeID as nvarchar(500)) + ' AttendeeID:' + CAST(@AttendeeID as nvarchar(500)) + ' SurveyID: ' + CAST(@SurveyID as nvarchar(500)) AS nvarchar(4000))
                --insert into our temp table    
                INSERT INTO #tSa(AttendeeID, SurveyID, TrainingAttendeeID) 
                VALUES(@AttendeeID, @SurveyID, @TrainingAttendeeID)
        END
END
GO
```

Comment: I dont understand the title... because `NOT EXIST (SELECT *` is the same as `NOT EXIST (SELECT 1`

Comment: dont usually say this.. but have you thought about using a cursor?  for `select distinct AttendeeID, SurveyID, TrainingAttendeeID`

Comment: @JamieD77 - I dont want to use a cursor, I'd really like to know why this isn't working as intended...Ill post the whole sproc...

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza- That is not my question, I can do SELECT 1...my question is why is it repeating the process of the same record over and over..I would of thought my NOT EXISTS...would have filtered it out.

Comment: well a WHILE will continue until the condition is false.. doesn't matter what the sql is doing..

Comment: @JamieD77 - Right...I understand that but the issue is it should NOT pick up any more records.  Hence the while ends I didnt post the whole while but i could post it...

Comment: But Jonh that is not the Title of your question :(

Comment: a cursor ends when there are not more records.. a while does not end until you physically set SomeCondition to false

Comment: If you want to know what is wrong you should there are a few things you can do. Reduce the problem to fewer tables, maybe use real table instead of temporal. Execute the query without a `WHILE` to see results.  And try replace `NOT EXISTS`  with `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE field IS NULL`

Comment: @JamieD77 - I posted the entire code..

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza- I have tried that...and everything looks good so far...the issue is I have inserted the record into my temp table.  The following in the where clause should NOT reuse this record: `AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tSa tempS INNER JOIN TrainingAttendee ta ON ta.TrainingAttendeeID=tempS.TrainingAttendeeID AND ta.AttendeeID = tempS.AttendeeID INNER JOIN TrainingSet ts ON ts.SurveyID = tempS.SurveyID WHERE tempS.AttendeeID = ta.AttendeeID AND tempS.SurveyID = ts.SurveyID AND tempS.TrainingAttendeeID = ta.TrainingAttendeeID))` but somehow it keeps processing the record...

Comment: when you do PRINT do you keep seeing the same values?

Comment: @JamieD77 - Yes I've mentioned that in the comments and the code posted...and that is my issue...Its as if my last condition isn't correct.

Comment: your NOT EXISTS doesnt make sense.. just compare to the main query.. no need to rejoin those tables

Comment: @JamieD77 I did that but accidentally joined to see if that was the issue I can remove those in the posted code...I mean to say I had that originally and only changed it due to making sure I wasn't experiencing some strange issue.  I edited the code to show you what I have...same issue.

Comment: Jhon the problem is we cant reproduce your issue, try creating a small verificable example in sqlfiddle [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Otherwise this will be a guessing game

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - So what you see in my condition seems to be correct?

Comment: yes, I do. On first glanze should work. Im building a smaller example to test.

Comment: I dont get why its not working...I mean my PRINT statement shows the same values being used over and over...yet every query I have pulled out and tried to run outside of this procedure is showing me the correct data...so why on earth is this happening...been stuck for hours :|.

Comment: Seems like since the last `SELECT TOP 1` does not find a record.. it never changes the values of @AttendeeID, @SurveyID @TrainingAttendeeID so they always remain the last value and are never null

Comment: @JamieD77 - Wouldn't that set the columns to NULL provided no record is found?

Comment: @JamieD77 - Wouldn't that set the columns to NULL provided no record is found?  I just did a test and it sets the values to NULL when no record is found...again I don't know why this is happening everything I do outside of this sproc seems to work as expected.

Comment: you didnt set the values before you tested it.. use `DECLARE @AttendeeID INT = 1` and then set the value from empty result and it will still be 1

Comment: Will test when I get home.

Comment: Jamie what should I do to avoid this?

Comment: just do what @Ivan said in his answer and put `SELECT @TrainingAttendeeID = NULL, @AttendeeID = NULL, @SurveyID = NULL` right after `WHILE BEGIN`

Comment: I'd have to do it right before the select as I use these values in my email.  Always thought SQL did this automatically.  Guess you learn something new each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables will not change if select does not return any records. I bet it processes last @AttendeeID round and round.

Another way to test it - add unique constraint to temp table. I assume cycle will fail once there are no more records to select.

One way to fix it - **assign NULLs to all variables at the beginning of each iteration** (at the top of `while` body). But I'd recommend to rewrite this code to cursor if possible (not sure what is the logic of several select statements).

Note that declaration of variables within code block makes no "block-scope" sense since it is not perl or python.